# Chromium Snap new profile with master_preferences

Tags: 20.04, chromium, snap

Chromium provides a few ways to pre-load bookmarks, extensions, and other settings on a brand new profile. One of those is the `master_preferences` file.

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences

On Linux, this file is usually placed at `/etc/chromium/master_preferences` or `/usr/lib/chromium/master_preferences` and read when launching chromium with no existing profile (e.g. `chromium-browser --user-data-dir=~/new_profile`). This worked once upon a time (using the .deb install of chromium afaik), but I cannot get it to work now.

I have a feeling this is due to the new Snap container having its own sandboxed filesystem and, being a read-only filesystem, I can't simply drop this preferences file into the container. Has Ubuntu's snap chromium been configured to read the `master_preferences` from elsewhere? Is there some other way to get this preferences file working?

Here's a sample `master_preferences` that should set Google as the homepage and add a "Home" button to the UI.

```
{
  "homepage": "https://google.com",
  "homepage_is_newtabpage": false
}
```

Comment: Just hit this issue. Have you been able to figure out a solution?

Comment: I have not figured it out, unfortunately.